# SDL2 keyboard detection doesn't work

Tags: c++, keyboard, sdl, sdl-2

I try to make a simple game using sdl2 for handling keyboard events. But the main problem is that neither in Clion embedded console nor in external console my program can't detect any event, only `SDL_AUDIODEVICEADDED` is caught twice at start of the program. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "include/SDL2/SDL_keyboard.h"
#include "include/SDL2/SDL_keycode.h"
#include "include/SDL2/SDL_scancode.h"

#include "include/SDL2/SDL.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv []) {
    SDL_Event event;
    bool running = true;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    int x, y;
    while(running){

        if(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            switch(event.type){
                case SDL_QUIT: running = false; break; 
                case SDL_KEYDOWN: 
                    switch(event.key.keysym.sym){ 
                        case SDLK_q: 
                            running = false;
                            break; 
                    }
                    break;

                case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    SDL_GetMouseState(&x, &y); 
                    cout << "[SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN] " << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << "\n";
                    break;
                case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                    x = event.motion.x;
                    y = event.motion.y;
                    cout << "[SDL_MOUSEMOTION] " << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << "\n";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`SDL_Init` returns 0.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that's your problem, but I'd take a look at this lazy foo's tutorial http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/03_event_driven_programming/index.php. I see he does the polling in a slightly different way (`while` vs `if`). I would think there's a sort of timing problem between when you generate the event and when your code tries to poll it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a window.

Keyboard and mouse events depend on a display surface. Only mouse actions within a window and keyboard input while the window is in focus will be captured. After all, you shouldn't be able to receive input possibly directed at other applications.

Comment: are you sure?   There is a window id field but it's not guaranteed to be populated.  I remember having to deal with issues because I was assuming these events had a window id but they didn't.